# What's the usage for Host header in http?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, http, rest, tomcat

In the http protocol, I saw sometimes we have a HOST header, like

```
Host: www.google.com:3333
```

what's the usage for this header? Why do we need this header?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When an http request hits a server, it only hits an IP/Port combination. This header shows which host was actually requested.

Many machines serve multiple hosts from the same IP. Without this header, they wouldn't know which host was requested.

Answer (score 0):

Answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3364144/is-port-number-required-in-http-host-header-parameter).

> See section [14.23 of the HTTP spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.23) which specifies that the port
>   should be included if its not the default port of 80.