# Hosting multiple websites on EC2 with ELB and HTTPS

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, iis, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

Setup within the AWS ecosystem is multiple web sites across 2 domains using ELB, SSL, IIS & ASP.NET across 2 EC2 instances.

After a security audit, we discovered our cookies weren't set to secure, so I setup a URL rewrite to look for the appropriate header from ELB and set HTTPS to true.  The problem is, users started getting emails stating https://www.test.com:80/ as the domain and unfortunately, we have too many references to Request.Url to make a change quickly.

Obviously IIS requires a different IP address (or port number) to host 2 SSL certificates.  If we change the port number, we'll still have the same issue, so we were hoping to add a secondary IP address and point ELB to use it, but that doesn't appear to be supported.  I'm fairly new to AWS, so I was hoping someone could give me some direction in terms of getting SSL to terminate within IIS on ELB.

So what I am asking is, is there a way to get ELB to use a specific IP Address instead of a generic EC2 instance which uses the primary IP Address?

Thank you in advance,

Andrew

Answer (score 0):

> If we change the port number, we'll still have the same issue,

No, you wouldn't.

Set up a second ELB using standard ports toward the Internet and custom ports toward the instance(s).

Comment: In ASP.NET wouldn't Request.Url return https://www.test.com:44300 if you used 44300 as the port number?

Comment: Well, it *shouldn't* be, because the port used for connecting to the instance by the balancer shouldn't appear in the `Host:` header, because the balancer shouldn't put it there -- unlike what would be expected if you pointed a browser directly at `example.com:43000`, in which case [it would](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3364396/1695906). Probably worth investigating.  I run non-MS web servers behind ELB on strange ports and have never even considered this something to expect to be broken.

Comment: However, this follow up does potentially explain what you were talking about with regard to `https://www.test.com:80/`, which, previously, made no sense to me at all.