# Remove port number from a url in java

Tags: java, url, port, uri

I want to write a function in java which removes the port if it is the default port.

So if given

```
String url80 = "http://www.somewhere.com:80/someplace";
```

it will return

```
String urlNo80 = "http://www.somewhere.com/someplace";
```

And if given

```
String url443 = "https://www.somewhere.com:443/someplace";
```

It will return

```
String urlNo443 = "https://www.somewhere.com/someplace";
```

Is there a better way to do it than

```
public String removePortIfDefault(String inUrl) {
    String returnUrl = inUrl;
    if (inUrl.contains("http://") && inUrl.contains(":80")) {
        returnUrl = inUrl.replaceAll(":80", "");
    }
    if (inUrl.contains("https://") && inUrl.contains(":443")) {
        returnUrl = inUrl.replaceAll(":443", "");
    }
    return returnUrl;
}
```

Comment: You can use URL.getDefaultPort().  See the second part of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46669187/1831987).

Comment: @VGR: Your comment should be the accepted and upvoted answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use string manipulation to work with a URL. Java has classes for that.

```java
String url80 = "http://www.somewhere.com:80/someplace";
```

```java
// Using java.net.URI
URI uri = URI.create(url80);
uri = new URI(uri.getScheme(), uri.getHost(), uri.getPath(), uri.getFragment());
String urlNo80 = uri.toString(); // http://www.somewhere.com/someplace
```

```java
// Using java.net.URL
URL url = new URL(url80);
url = new URL(url.getProtocol(), url.getHost(), url.getFile());
String urlNo80 = url.toString(); // http://www.somewhere.com/someplace
```

Comment: *BEWARE*: Yes, this turns `http://www.somewhere.com:80/someplace` into `http://www.somewhere.com/someplace`, but it also turns `http://www.somewhere.com:1234/someplace` into `http://www.somewhere.com/someplace` which means this is a very dangerous solution in my opinion.

Comment: In another context, this is a usable solution, I don't think you need to warn us about this obvious effect

Answer (score 3):

You can use replaceFirst (or replaceAll) with a regular expression

```
String urlNo80 = url80.replaceFirst(":\\d+", "");
```

Comment: This won't work if `:8809` is somewhere completely else in the URL...

Comment: And where would that be? I’m not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: Is that really a valid url?

Comment: In my case, I have to use RegExp in replace pattern _':\\d+'_  =>
`String urlNo80 = url80.replaceFirst(RegExp(r':\d+'), '');`